# Почему конструктор std::unique_ptr при создание переменной - члена класса ругается, что требуется спецификатор типа

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Если использовать конструктор для умного указателя, который принимает указатель на переменную, то все нормально работает в основном коде, но в классах, при попытке создать переменную - член типа std::unique_ptr(new type) - ругается компилятор(VS community 2019), что требуется спецификатор типа и принимает создание умного указателя только через std::make_unique. Объясните, пожалуйста,
почему так происходит, а не как исправить

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class A {
public:
    A() { std::cout << "A created\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "A destroyed\n"; }
};

class B {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a(new A);//???
/*std::unique_ptr a = std::make_unique<A>() - works*/
public:
    B() { std::cout << "B created\n"; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "B destroyed\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a(new A);//Works
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вынесите инициализацию в конструктор

Comment: Мне не понятно, почему так происходит, а не как исправить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае инициализация поля с использованием синтаксиса copy initialization (то бишь с круглыми скобочками) парсится как объявление метода c именем `a`. При инициализации полей внутри класса, да и во всех других случаях, следует использовать синтаксис [direct list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (который также хорош тем, что не допускает понижающих преобразований с потерей данных).

```
class B {
std::unique_ptr<A> a{new A{}};

public:
B() { std::cout << "B created\n"; }
~B() { std::cout << "B destroyed\n"; }
};
```

Comment: Я думал, здесь будет использоваться прямая инициализация с вызовом конструктора. Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Инициализация членов класса в месте их определения возможна двумями способами:

- через `=`
- через `{}`

```
struct S {
    int a = 1; // ok
    int b {2}; // ok
    int c (3); // ошибка
};
```

Вы пытаетесь использовать третий и получаете ошибку.